# Html translation with parameters in symfony3 / twig

Tags: forms, symfony, twig, translate, twig-filter

I have a pb with a translation containing parameters (link href). I have added a `|raw` but I see the html displayed.

My code :

```
{{ form_row(form.valid, {

'label' : 'annonces.form.valide_cgu_cgv' | trans ({

'cgu_link' : path('page_statique', {'page' : 'cgu'}),

'cgv_link' : path('page_statique', {'page' : 'cgv'})

}) | raw }) }}
```

What I see :

`Je reconnais accepter les <a href="/page/cgu">Conditions générales d'utilisation</a> et <a href="/page/cgv">Conditions générales de vente</a>`

Any idea ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the form_label use `trans()` without the `raw` inside of its code

```
{%- block form_label -%}
    {# [...] #}
        <label{% for attrname, attrvalue in label_attr %} {{ attrname }}="{{ attrvalue }}"{% endfor %}>{{ label|trans({}, translation_domain) }}</label>
    {%- endif -%}
{%- endblock form_label -%}
```

You need either to use a custom `form_label` or 'manually' display the label

Comment: That was the pb ! Tks !